# error in connecting bluetooth device

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

i have an error and cant find  solution any ideas ?
here is the error : The method listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(String, UUID) in the type BluetoothAdapter is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

```
tmp = mBlue.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("repeat","82c116ca-26b1-11e3-9851-f23c91aec05e");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method signiture requires a String and UUID, you are supplying a String and a String.

For the second paramater you need to parse the String into a UUID as follows

```
tmp = mBlue.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("repeat",UUID.fromString"82c116ca-26b1-11e3-9851-f23c91aec05e"));
```

Comment: thanks alot:)
do u know how can i connect to a device after the discovery once i click on it ?

Comment: you will have to give me a little more information than that. ;) But I suggest you look at the Bluetooth Chat Example from the Android SDK. It has most of the connection stuff all worked out. [And here's the dev docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

Comment: i looked in the example but i can't connect to a device !!
i've written a code that turn on the bluetooth , make it discover-able and then scan for nearby devices but i want to connect to one of the devices and its not working !